# Should I add "(s)" to labels for fields that can have 1 or many options selected?

Tags: labels, multi-selection, best-practice

Are there any best practices for adding "(s)" to a label on a field that can have more than 1 option selected?

I think it looks cleaner without the "(s)", but having the "(s)" seems to help with usability.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My rule of thumb...

**For fields that allow ONLY ONE selection:** `Oldest Student`

**For fields that allow MORE THAN ONE selection:** `Students`

The question is really asking for *all of the answers* to the question, even if the number of answers turns out being 1... the query was still for *all* (plural). This follows in line with how you'd ask the question in plain English. For example, if it were a verbal question you'd likely ask...

> Which *students* are in your class?